# Bind on method inside object. Gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind

I was trying to call bind inside a JavaScript object in **node.js** like so.

```
var obj = {
  m: function () {
    console.log(this)
  }.bind(obj),
}
```

When I call `obj.m()`, I was expecting `this` inside function `m` to be `obj`. But the global object is getting printed.

Can anyone explain why this happens.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Can you explain how obj being in the global scope is related to global object being printed.

Comment: Guess I was wrong, answer below addresses the issue

Comment: What is the point of binding? Are you going to use the method as an event listener?

Comment: @Teemu I was just figuring out how bind works. And came across this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object literal has to be *completely* evaluated before it is assigned to `obj`.

At the time you call `bind(obj)`, the value of `obj` is still `undefined`.

Hence, the global object is bound.

Comment: So passing undefined to bind, Makes the function bound to global object or window object ?